# Counting words from user input text file

Tags: java

I am having trouble counting the amount of words in a given text file. Every time I input a text file name, the program returns "File not found". Here is the code I have so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println("Enter File name: ");
        Scanner input=new Scanner (System.in);
        String fileName= input.nextLine();
        FileReader wordReader;
        try {
            wordReader=new FileReader(fileName);
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(wordReader);
            String cursor;
            String content="";
            int numberWords=0;
            while((cursor=reader.readLine()) !=null) {
                String []_words=cursor.split("");
                for(String w: _words)
                {
                    numberWords++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Total words: "+ numberWords);
        }catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("File not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to input the absolute file path, eg: C:/dir/file.txt?

Comment: Yes! Thank you, it now reads the file, but does not count the total number of words correctly :/

Comment: @Chandler Bing has the answer ;)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't splitting correctly. Split by `" "` instead of `""`

```
String []_words=cursor.split(" "); //-------------> Add Space
```

This will give you the words instead of individual characters.

Also, you could just print `_words.length` instead of looping unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("sample.txt");
try(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file))){
    int count=0;
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        sc.next();
        count++;
    }
System.out.println("Number of words: " + count);
}
```